# t32 read symbols if we give symbol table and string table section from ELF file

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

We have stripped ELF where symbol table and string table stripped from ELF binary and copied to as symtab.bin and strtab.bin.
Copy is done using file operations where we read section symbtab, strtab start offset to size and write to symtab.bin and strtab.bin

We want to load symbol data from symtab.bin and strtab.bin instead of giving elf checked t32 manual but it seems we need to create symbol with name and address

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, this is needed to debug production (stripped) ELF.

I specially checked the manual https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/general_ref_d.pdf and I'm absolutely sure that there is no such possibility.

My solution is to send lauterbach.com a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of the terminal commands `file symtab.bin` and `file strtab.bin`?

If the output is something like "ELF LSB relocatable etc.", then you can run `Data.LOAD.Elf <file> /NoClear /NoCODE`. You also might need to use the `/RELOC` setting. For a binary, it still might be possible using `Data.LOAD.Binary` or `Data.LOAD.sYm` but you'd need to specify more/different options.

As a manual workaround, you can create a WHILE loop to read each line of the two files and run the desired command, whether that's `Data.LOAD.Binary <...> /SKIP &offset` or `sYmbol.CREATE` or `Data.Set`.

I'd imagine the functionality already exists for what you'd like to do, so contacting Lauterbach support is a good idea.

Comment: There's also a blog post about converting binary files back to .elf:
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2018/01/27/converting-a-raw-binary-file-into-an-elf-dwarf-file-for-loading-and-debugging/